# How to get correct integer value if we give more that 16 digit number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I am getting an input value (integer variable) more that 16 digit number not able to get correct value.

**HTML:**

```
<div><input id="number_id" value="111111111111111111"></div>
```

**Script:**

```
$("#number_id").blur(function(){
var ns = $("#number_id").val();
alert(Number(ns))
});
```

any one have solution please help me.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qntr2/

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript uses 64bit floating point numbers exclusively, which means you only get about 16 decimal digits of precision. This is a fundamental limitation of the number type.

You can store the digits as a string instead. If you need to do computations with numbers this big you'll have to use a library that implements arbitrary precision  arithmetic.

Comment: after getting value from input, i used that value for calculation, so calculation get wrong value.

Comment: Search for arbitrary precision or bignum libraries then. Here's one: https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/

Answer (score 2):

All number in javascript can be supported up to 9007199254740992, which is 16 digit numbers. If you store more than that, it will be interpreted wrong. 
(http://www.2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html)

The best way to do is to store it into string. If you want to do some basic things with big integer, you can use this https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum